# Cordova: Launching chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files from VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

I'm working on a cordova application in Visual Studio 2017 and I'm trying to access the filesystem using the file plugin. Unfortunately this does not work when debugging the application using 'Simulate in browser' (using cordova-simulate).

A 'SecurityError: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources.' error is raised.

I guess if have to pass '--allow-file-access-from-files' option to chrome, but I don't know how to do this, because chrome is launched automatically in a new window and I cannot find any configuration options in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Colin Hi, once you build the browser platform using cordova CLI, you gotta navigate to '<project_root_folder>/platforms/browser/cordova' folder in command prompt. The run the command - 'run -- --target=chrome --port=8000 --allow-file-access-from-files'. you can find more info on the 'run' file available in '<project_root_folder>/platforms/browser/cordova' folder. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Some [Chrome Quirks](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#chrome-quirks) are:

- Chrome filesystem is not immediately ready after device ready event. As a workaround you can subscribe to `filePluginIsReady` event.
  **Example:** javascript `window.addEventListener('filePluginIsReady', function(){ console.log('File plugin is ready');}, false);` You can use `window.isFilePluginReadyRaised` function to check whether event was already raised.
- window.requestFileSystem TEMPORARY and PERSISTENT filesystem quotas are not limited in Chrome.
- To increase persistent storage in Chrome you need to call `window.initPersistentFileSystem` method. Persistent storage quota is 5 MB by default.
- Chrome requires **--allow-file-access-from-files** run argument to support API via `file:///` protocol.
- **File** object will be not changed if you use flag `{create:true}` when getting an existing `Entry`.

Form above quirks use basic steps [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/):

> At the time of writing this article, Google Chrome has the only working implementation of the FileSystem API. A dedicated browser UI does not yet exist for **file/quota** management. To store data on the user's system, may require your app to [request quota](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-requesting-quota). However, for testing, Chrome can be run with the **--unlimited-quota-for-files** flag. Furthermore, if you're building an app or extension for the Chrome Web Store, the **unlimitedStorage** manifest file permission can be used in place of requesting quota. Eventually, users will receive a permission dialog to grant, deny, or increase storage for an app.
>
> You may need the **--allow-file-access-from-files** flag if you're debugging your app from **file://**. Not using these flags will result in a **SECURITY_ERR** or **QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR** FileError.

Comment: Yes. But how do you launch chrome with --allow-file-access-from-files from VS 2017? See this linked question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100633/how-to-get-fileentry-object-while-using-cordova-simulate?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Colin For that type chrome://version in your Chrome address bar, and it will tell you what "command line" invocation you should be using. Just add **--allow-file-access-from-files** to that.

Comment: Thanks Asif, I tried this - added both `--allow-file-access-from-files` and `--unlimited-quota-for-files` to the command line, but found that I still got the security error